# Doctrine 2 OneToMany Cascade SET NULL

Tags: doctrine, null, set, one-to-many

## The error

Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails.

## The classes

```
class Teacher {

    /**
     *@ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="publication", mappedBy="teacher")
     */
    protected $publications;
}

class Publication {

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Teacher", inversedBy="publications")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="teacher_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $teacher;
}
```

## I want

What I want is to make it that when you delete a teacher, the id_teacher is modified to NULL. I want to keep the publication but without reference to Professor.

I don't know how do that in Doctrine, Is it possible? Or always the relationship has to be with a teacher?

Answer (score 210):

You should add the option `onDelete="SET NULL"` in the annotation of your entity Publication like this:

```php
class Publication
{
    /**
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Teacher", inversedBy="publications")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="teacher_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="SET NULL")
    */
    protected $teacher;
}
```

This modification is registered in the table declaration itself. Hence, you need a database migration or a schema change for this to take effect.

Comment: Please note that you have to update your database schema after you've added this.

Comment: * @ORM\JoinColumn(onDelete="SET NULL") is enough

Comment: This solution acts directly on the database and not on doctrine, which is fine but be careful if you use mechanisms like [soft-deleteable](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/v2.4.x/doc/softdeleteable.md). If your entity is being soft-deleted, it won't trigger SET_NULL and your child entity will point to a "deleted" object. You'll need to add a doctrine listener to make it work (depending on the behaviour you want).

Answer (score 7):

For Symfony 6 (PHP 8) (Engine 'InnoDB')

```
#[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: true, onDelete: 'SET NULL')]
```

Comment: Thank you, and for beginners, remember to run the following command after this change : 
`php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force`

Answer (score 0):

Old question, so this is for anyone searching for solution.

In case you **don't want to make any changes to database schema** you can make use of doctrine event system:

```php
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

...

#[ORM\PreRemove]
public function clearPublications(): void
{
    foreach ($this->getPublications() as $publication) {
        $publication->setTeacher(null);
    }
}
```