# Doctrine: cascade="remove" vs orphanRemoval=true

Tags: symfony, doctrine, cascade, cascading-deletes

What is the difference between the 2 options above? When is it preferable to choose each option?

Answer (score 153, accepted):

The basic difference between them is:

> When using the orphanRemoval=true option Doctrine makes the assumption
>   that the entities are privately owned and will NOT be reused by other
>   entities. If you neglect this assumption your entities will get
>   deleted by Doctrine even if you assigned the orphaned entity to
>   another one.

Say your *`User`* has **one-to-many** relation to *`Comment`*. If you are using `cascade="remove"`, you can remove the reference for *`Comment`* from one *`User`*, and then attach that *`Comment`* to another *`User`*. When you persist them, they will be correctly saved. But if you are using `orphanRemoval=true`, even if you will remove given *`Comment`* from one *`User`*, and then attach to another *`User`*, this comment will be deleted during persist, because the reference has been deleted.

Comment: @a2ad2d what does **"privately owned"** means? I know that orphanRemoval=true can by the way be used in ManyToMany Relationship

Comment: @Aleqxs can you provide an example?

Comment: @a2ad2d Category Entity and Article Entity in a ManyToMany relationship. see asked question on this subject [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27476333/what-does-the-entities-are-privately-owned-means-as-seen-in-doctrine-official?lq=1) and some of the test I did to delete in cascade [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27506876/deleting-entities-in-cascade-not-working-in-manytomany-relation)

Comment: @Aleqxs Sorry, but it seems that in case of ManyToMany, orphanRemoval doesn't make sense

Comment: @a2ad2d but it is written that it "works with Many-To-Many associations" in the [offical doctrine documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#orphan-removal) This is why I wonder what exactly means _**"privatly own"**_

Comment: @Aleqxs ok, i think that in your [case](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27506876/2431515) **privately owned** means your *Category* and it's references to *Article*

Comment: And if you don't assign the `comment` to another `user`, will the `comment` still be deleted even if you don't specify `orphanRemoval=true`?

Comment: @darkbluesun you can specify `onDelete="SET NULL"` if you want to save the comment correctly after user removing. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11691485/2431515) answer.