# Doctrine OneToMany collection clear() and orphanRemoval

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, nette

My Article Entity has collection $internalAuthors

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity = "ArticleModule\Model\Entities\ArticleInternalAuthor", mappedBy = "article", cascade = {"persist"})
 */
protected $internalAuthors;
```

If I want to clear this collection ($this->internalAuthors->clear()), collection is cleared, but data are still in database.

I must call DQL for delete that authors from database. But I prefer have this kind of logic in entity. I noticed, if I add orphanRemoval = TRUE, to OneToMany declaration, then data are removed also from database.

Is it correct usage of orphanRemoval? Should I use something else?

Comment: Have you done $entityManager->flush()?

Comment: Sure. And it works with orphanRemoval = TRUE (not working without orphanRemoval). My main question is, if it is correct usage...

Comment: Yep, that's proper solution. You can find detailed explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25519856/1348344