# Doctrine 2 : ManyToOne cascade remove causes the referenced entity to be deleted

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, cascade, cascading-deletes

I have a setup where I have product feeds, and each feed has many products. The very simplified setup looks something like this:

Feed model:

```
/**
 * Class Feed represents a single feed as supplier by a supplier
 * @package App\Model
 * @Entity @Table(name="feeds")
 */
class Feed
{
    /**
     * @var int
     * @Id @Column(type="integer") @GeneratedValue
     */
    protected $id;
}
```

Product model:

```
/**
 * Class Product is the base for either supplied and current products
 * @package App\Model
 */
class Product
{
    /**
     * @var int
     * @Id @Column(type="integer") @GeneratedValue
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var Feed
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Model\Feed", cascade={"remove"})
     * @JoinColumn(name="id_feed", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    protected $feed;
}
```

Now as you can see I have cascading enabled, because I want all of the products to be deleted automatically when a feed is deleted.

However... At the moment, when I delete a product, it causes the original feed te be deleted as well. I suspect it has something to do with how the relation is setup, but I can't seem to figure out where it's wrong.

Can anyone show more light on this situation?

Comment: I think you should define this cascade in Feed class on "OneToMany" mapped to your products. Actually, you have defined unidirectional relation. You have to defined bidirectional relation

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Kind of new to doctrine. I was thinking about how CASCADE works in MySQL, where you only have to define it on the orphans, so I thought it had a similar approach in Doctrine.

Comment: Orm is quite a puzzle for me too ! But, once well set it's like magic. You can get more precised details in this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25515007/doctrine-cascade-remove-vs-orphanremoval-true?rq=1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Feed Model :**

```
    /**
     * Class Feed represents a single feed as supplier by a supplier
     * @package App\Model
     * @Entity @Table(name="feeds")
     */
    class Feed
    {
        /**
         * @var int
         * @Id @Column(type="integer") @GeneratedValue
         */
         protected $id;

       /**
        * @var Feed
        * @OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Model\Product", mappedBy="feed", orphanRemoval=true, cascade={"remove"})
        * 
        */
        protected $products;    

    }
```

**Product Model :**

```
/**
 * Class Product is the base for either supplied and current products
 * @package App\Model
 */
class Product
{
    /**
     * @var int
     * @Id @Column(type="integer") @GeneratedValue
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var Feed
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Model\Feed", inversedBy="products")
     * @JoinColumn(name="id_feed", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $feed;
}
```

Now, if you delete a Feed object, Product objects linked to this Feed will be deleted too.

This is bidirectional relation.

**More info :**

**cascade={"remove"}**

- Entity on the inverse side will be deleted while the owning side (Feed) is deleted but only if the entity (Product) is not owned by another than Feed.

**orphanRemoval="true"**

- Same as above but ORM ignores if entity (Product) is owned by another Entity