# Sonata Admin Image Field

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, sonata-media-bundle

I am using the Sonata Admin back-end and I would like to add a **new image field** to my user entity which is an avatar. Since I am already using the `SonataMediaBundle` I followed this tutorial: https://sonata-project.org/blog/2013/10/11/mediabundle-mediatype-improved

Here is my entity configuration:

```
/**
 * @var \Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\Media
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\Media", cascade={"all"}, fetch="LAZY")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="avatar_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $avatar;
```

Unfortunately I have many problems:

1. In my back-end the preview is not shown:
   [image]
2. If I delete the media in the gallery I receive this error when editing the user: `Entity of type 'Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\Media' for IDs id(6) was not found`
3. The resulting API (generated with FOSRestBundle) is unusable by the client:

> ```
> "avatar": {
>         "provider_metadata": {
>             "filename": "Test.png"
>         },
>         "name": "Test.png",
>         "description": null,
>         "enabled": false,
>         "provider_name": "sonata.media.provider.image",
>         "provider_status": 1,
>         "provider_reference": "325564b03489a6473e7c9def01dc58bab611eccb.png",
>         "width": 1430,
>         "height": 321,
>         "length": null,
>         "copyright": null,
>         "author_name": null,
>         "context": "default",
>         "cdn_is_flushable": null,
>         "cdn_flush_at": null,
>         "cdn_status": null,
>         "updated_at": "2017-08-08T12:31:19+02:00",
>         "created_at": "2017-08-08T12:31:19+02:00",
>         "content_type": "image/png",
>         "size": 24978,
>         "id": 7
>     }
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved all the 3 problems! I put here my solutions for all those who have the same difficulties.

> 1. In my back-end the preview is not shown:

As explained [here](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/media/master/doc/reference/form.html) I have to add a custom form widget to my `config.yml` file:

```
twig:
    # Sonata form themes
    form_themes:
        - 'SonataMediaBundle:Form:media_widgets.html.twig'
```

And in my `UserAdmin`:

```
->with('Profile')
    ->add('avatar', 'sonata_media_type', array(
        'provider' => 'sonata.media.provider.image',
        'context'  => 'default',
    ))
->end()
```

Now the preview will be shown :)

> 2. If I delete the media in the gallery I receive this error when editing the user: Entity of type
>      'Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\Media' for IDs id(6) was not
>      found

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8858645/doctrine-2-onetomany-cascade-set-null) I need to add `onDelete="SET NULL"` on my entity:

```
/**
 * @var \Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\Media
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\Media", cascade={"persist"}, fetch="LAZY")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="avatar_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="SET NULL")
 */
protected $avatar;
```

> 3. The resulting API (generated with FOSRestBundle) is unusable by the client:

This one was very tricky but I was able to implement a custom JMS handler getting started from [this](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataMediaBundle/issues/363) post.

I peeked into the `SonataMediaBundle` source code and I found this snippet:

```
/**
 * Returns media urls for each format.
 *
 * @ApiDoc(
 *  requirements={
 *      {"name"="id", "dataType"="integer", "requirement"="\d+", "description"="media id"}
 *  },
 *  statusCodes={
 *      200="Returned when successful",
 *      404="Returned when media is not found"
 *  }
 * )
 *
 * @param $id
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function getMediumFormatsAction($id)
{
    $media = $this->getMedium($id);

    $formats = array(MediaProviderInterface::FORMAT_REFERENCE);
    $formats = array_merge($formats, array_keys($this->mediaPool->getFormatNamesByContext($media->getContext())));

    $provider = $this->mediaPool->getProvider($media->getProviderName());

    $properties = array();
    foreach ($formats as $format) {
        $properties[$format]['url'] = $provider->generatePublicUrl($media, $format);
        $properties[$format]['properties'] = $provider->getHelperProperties($media, $format);
    }

    return $properties;
}
```

So I included it into my source and the complete handler is the following:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Serializer;

use Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\Media;
use JMS\Serializer\Context;
use JMS\Serializer\GraphNavigator;
use JMS\Serializer\Handler\SubscribingHandlerInterface;
use JMS\Serializer\JsonSerializationVisitor;
use Sonata\MediaBundle\Provider\MediaProviderInterface;

class MediaHandler implements SubscribingHandlerInterface
{
    private $mediaPool;

    public function __construct($mediaPool)
    {
        $this->mediaPool = $mediaPool;
    }

    public static function getSubscribingMethods()
    {
        return array(
            array(
                'direction' => GraphNavigator::DIRECTION_SERIALIZATION,
                'format'    => 'json',
                'type'      => 'Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\Media',
                'method'    => 'serializeToJson',
            ),
        );
    }

    public function serializeToJson(JsonSerializationVisitor $visitor, Media $media, array $type, Context $context)
    {
        $formats = array(MediaProviderInterface::FORMAT_REFERENCE);
        $formats = array_merge($formats, array_keys($this->mediaPool->getFormatNamesByContext($media->getContext())));

        $provider = $this->mediaPool->getProvider($media->getProviderName());

        $properties = array();
        foreach ($formats as $format) {
            $properties[$format]['url']        = $provider->generatePublicUrl($media, $format);
            $properties[$format]['properties'] = $provider->getHelperProperties($media, $format);
        }

        return $properties;
    }
}
```

Service settings:

```
app.serializer.media:
    class: AppBundle\Serializer\MediaHandler
    arguments:
      - '@sonata.media.pool'
    tags:
        - { name: jms_serializer.subscribing_handler }
```

And that's all!