# How to update the table row on delete row in another table using Doctrine?

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm

I have entity "A" with the following property:

```yaml
manyToOne:
    b:
        targetEntity: App\Entity\B
        joinColumn:
            name: b_id
            referencedColumnName: id
```

How can I update the value of entity "A", when delete the entity "B", instantly?

e.g.:

```php
$a = new A();
$b = $bRepository->find(1);
$a->setB($b);
$em->persist($a);
$em->flush();

// table a:         table b:
// +----+------+    +----+
// | id | b_id |    | id |
// +----+------+    +----+
// |  1 |    1 |    |  1 |
// +----+------+    +----+

$em->remove($b);
$em->flush();

// table a:         table b:
// +----+------+    +----+
// | id | b_id |    | id |
// +----+------+    +----+
// |  1 | NULL |
// +----+------+
```

I can do it with the MySQL trigger, but maybe there exists some configuration for table or doctrine  to do it w\o triggers?

The main problem is that I can't modify the entity "B"  or update entity "A" with `$a->setB(null); $em->persist($a);` on "B" removing, because it in shared bundle and using in several projects

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Doctrine 2 OneToMany Cascade SET NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8858645/doctrine-2-onetomany-cascade-set-null)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution I didn't noticed before: [MySQL "ON DELETE" referential action](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)  with value "SET NULL". See the fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/49e79b/1

```sql
ALTER TABLE a ADD FOREIGN KEY (b_id) REFERENCES b (id) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

```yaml
manyToOne:
    b:
        targetEntity: App\Entity\B
        joinColumn:
            name: b_id
            referencedColumnName: id
            onDelete: SET NULL
```